# Has class isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery method that is supposed to check if the menu is open (with the class) and if the click happened ouside of the element with that class.

So far it cancels out the cart from opening because it will immediately add the class (open) the remove the class.

I'm not sure what is going on as that's not what I told my code to do.

Any ideas?

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (jQuery('body').hasClass("cbp-spmenu-push-toleft") == true 
        && jQuery(e.target).hasClass('cbp-spmenu-open') == false) 
    {
        console.log('clock')
        jQuery('body').removeClass('cbp-spmenu-push-toleft')
        jQuery('#cbp-spmenu-s2').removeClass('cbp-spmenu-open')
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding the class like its mentioned in the question?

Comment: Can you provide more code. Like e.a. the HTML and the other Javascript parts.

Comment: Are you writing on click binding code correctly, http://api.jquery.com/on/ ? You can check it by putting an alert/log b4 if has body class condition.

Comment: And are you catching the click event from the document? You need to replace document with the element youre clicking on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.target`This refers to any element where the click happened not the one you think it will be

you should put

```
//$(document)
$("#cbp-spmenu-s2").on('click', function () {
  if ($('body').hasClass("cbp-spmenu-push-toleft")&&!$(this).hasClass('cbp-spmenu-open')) {
    console.log('clock')
    $('body').removeClass('cbp-spmenu-push-toleft');
    $('#cbp-spmenu-s2').removeClass('cbp-spmenu-open');
  }
});
```